# Children not calling parent constructor

Tags: php

We got a huge PHP project with a lot of dirty classes.

If there is a parent class defining a property in its constructor like `$this->prop = true` and unknown child classes extend that parent class without calling the parent construct, but using parent methods that use the property `$this->prop = true`, this will lead to an error.

What is the best solution for this problem?

- always check `if ( $this->prop ) ...`
- search out all children construct and add calls to the parent?
- ...

Thanks.

Comment: Child should always call the base in the ctor. This is specifically why. If you don't want to call the super ctor, then you probably want to implement an interface rather than extend a super class.

Comment: It's sad when children don't call their parents.

Comment: Children should always call the parent constructor, however it is still not best practise to randomly use properties or variables without checking they are set

Comment: Why not just call `parent::__construct()`?

Comment: @Anigel, he should be able to assume they are "set" after the ctor has been called if they are a member of the class...he just needs to check if they are the "valid" value.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

#2: Search out all children and add parent::__construct() to their construct.